# How can I make a product showcase in Silverlight?

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, silverlight-3.0

I can place a couple of buttons in Silverlight, but I'm not that experienced with the Silverlight tools and capabilities.

What do you think I should use to create something like this?
[image]

The control would have to pull and ID from the database and according to that place an image asociated with the record.

I need it to be animated with some crispy movement.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: This looks like a full project to me, this question is really difficult to answer as it will be too lengthy to explain every steps involved.

Comment: By the way, this is not ten years ago and Silverlight is not Flash. If this is for a public-facing web site, I strongly suggest you rather look at using JavaScript and graceful degradation (your products would actually be in a list, the animation enhances it to look nicer) to insure your site is usable by most people and the information reaches everyone.

Answer (score 0):

It's all possible, but you need to break the task down into smaller steps.

Once you've done that you should find that you can solve some of these with your current knowledge, others will resolve themselves with a little more research, but there will be some you need to ask questions about here.

I'd suggest you start that break down and try to solve the little problems. Then if you get stuck come back and ask more specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

Well, with Silverlight and c# you can make the animations needed and such, and you can set a Silverlight Image control with a data bound source, so it loads the images dynamically, but Silverlight can't talk with databases directly, you'll need to use a webservice to interact between Silverlight and the database. Don't know how much you know but to not leave anything out, with Expression Blend you can make the graphical part of you're app fast and easy, and with Visual Studio you'll add the code-behind and functionality.

In [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/Silverlight3_Slideshow.aspx) you can find a example of how to make an image slide show with Silverlight, it may not be exactly what you're looking for, but it should give you a heads start.